# Sylius: What Routes did a Resource Create?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

Is there any way -- either a debugging command or heuristic -- to know what routes a Sylius resource has created?

That is, I know I can debug a resource's configuration

```
$ php bin/console sylius:debug:resource sylius.order
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| name               | order                                                 |
| application        | sylius                                                |
| driver             | doctrine/orm                                          |
| classes.model      | App\Entity\Order\Order                                |
| classes.controller | Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Controller\OrderController   |
| classes.repository | Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Doctrine\ORM\OrderRepository |
| classes.interface  | Sylius\Component\Order\Model\OrderInterface           |
| classes.factory    | Sylius\Component\Resource\Factory\Factory             |
| classes.form       | Sylius\Bundle\OrderBundle\Form\Type\OrderType         |
+--------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

but this doesn't list any routes.  I would like to be able to know, at a glance, which route identifiers the `sylius.order` *resource* automatically created.

Comment: Is "php bin/console debug:router | grep order" giving what you need?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to get routes which uses an resource. IMO the best way is to search routes manually which have resource controller service id keyword (for example, `sylius.controller.order`) in YML files in /vendor directory. But it won't work with [autogenerated generic CRUD](https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/components_and_bundles/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/routing.html#generating-generic-crud-routing)